# Customization of list of acronyms

Tags: horizontal-alignment, glossaries, columns

I am beginner, and new here. I have similar problem to one mentioned here:

[Right align first column of glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169090/right-align-first-column-of-glossary/374713?noredirect=1#comment926887_374713)

But I would like also to have increased distance between acronym and definition. I have already implemented solution in link above.

Thanks a lot, Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

You could add some manual space between the columns of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{mysuper}{%
  \setglossarystyle{super}% base style on the list style
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
      {\tablehead{}\tabletail{}%
       \begin{supertabular}{r@{\hskip 1in}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
      {\end{supertabular}}%
}
\setglossarystyle{mysuper}

\newglossaryentry{Example}{name=Example, description=an example}
\newglossaryentry{EX}{name=EX, description=another example}

\begin{document}

I use \gls{Example} and \gls{EX} in my text.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]